# Button click not working in safari browser alone

Tags: jquery, html, safari

Once I enter an invalid customer and click on the button(verifyCustId-btn) 4 times, the button gets disabled and blocks from clicking again.Except Safari , all other browsers allow me to click on the button(verifyCustId-btn) 'n' number of times.Iam facing this issue in Safari alone.Please help me to get this resolved.

```
$('#verifyCustId-btn').click(function (e) {
        var mobNumber = $("#txtCustId").val();
        if ($("#txtCustId").val() == '') {
            alertify.error("Not a valid customer");

            return false;
        }
        else if ($("#txtCustId").val() != '')
            checkCustomerCode();

         return;
     });
```

Comment: what do you mean by disabled?

Comment: can you add the code of : checkCustomerCode?

Comment: button is visible...but  'onclick' function is not working after the fourth click

Comment: Actually iam checking with only the "IF" part , where no value is entered in textbox and trying to click verify button four times